# Get polygons of crop classification from the Land Parcel Information Systems (LPIS)

Tags: qgis, land-classification, parcel, image-classification

I'm trying to get\download polygons of fields with crop type. There is a USA database called [cropscape](https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/) which is very friendly. There is also a European one called [Land Parcel Information\Indentification Systems (LPIS)](https://ec.europa.eu/jrc/en/publication/eur-scientific-and-technical-research-reports/land-parcel-identification-system-lpis-anomalies-sampling-and-spatial-pattern-towards) which some academic papers used for their study, e.g., [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjG4JiqkeDmAhVU5eAKHTECDL4QFjABegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2072-4292%2F10%2F6%2F911%2Fpdf-vor&usg=AOvVaw3WxBh7u44nzlma0avTDgHq). 
However, the information regarding this database is not clear. I cannot find relevant information directing me to how can I obtain field polygons from this data (if it is possible).

Did someone used this data in the past?

Comment: Lpis is part of the common agricultural payments system and is not generally available to the public. It will also be held on a region by region basis, so could be hard to acquire for the whole of Europe

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks, let's say I would like to get polygons of fields in north Italy, how do I proceed from here? is there an agency to talk to? I understand that this might cost money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the (anonymized) LPIS as open data here:

## Austria

#### Datasets (most probably EPSG:31297)

- 2019 [metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/e21a731f-9e08-4dd3-b9e5-cd460438a5d9) | [direct link to gpkg](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2019.gpkg.zip)
- 2018 [metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/f7691988-e57c-4ee9-bbd0-e361d3811641) | [direct link to gpkg](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2018.gpkg.zip)
- 2017 [metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/d3b0cdeb-5727-46dd-8de4-a76f1898fd9b) | [direct link to gpkg](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2017.gpkg.zip)
- 2016 [metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/3a137b8c-ecae-42ba-a45c-f1ee6a24d1d4) | [direct link to gpkg](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2016.gpkg.zip)
- 2015 [metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/6f0b2311-1373-40a9-9e83-1fad54b3de91) | [direct link to gpkg](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2015.gpkg.zip)

#### Attributes:

- `FS_KENNUNG`: unique ID
- `SNAR_BEZEICHNUNG`: crop type

## Wallonia

#### Datasets (EPSG:31370)

- 2018 [metadata](https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/download_details.html?view=downloadDetails&resourceId=%2FINSPIRE-f5201eb0-2404-11e5-8130-52540004b857_20200527-060002%2Fservices%2F1%2FPullResults%2F121-140%2Fdatasets%2F11&expandedSection=metadata) | [direct link to shp](https://geoservices.wallonie.be/geotraitement/spwdatadownload/get/44b10a46-4025-4020-a943-e8ffd5ccbd21/PARC_AGRI_ANON_2018_SHAPE_31370.zip)

#### Attributes

- `cult_cod`: crop type id
- `cult_nom`: crop type
- `groupe_cul`: crop type group

Comment: thanks, but I could not find where to download the data, only some metadata as xml, can you direct me to how to download it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide the direct link to the Geopackage

Comment: Thanks, I understand that this is for 2019, is it possible to get the same data for other years? do you have an idea of where I can find similar data for other countries?

Comment: I have added more data. Beware that ids are not identical for each parcel across years.

Comment: Wow, thank you! The ID's are less important for me, I just need, the polygons, the crops, and the year. Does each country have its own "policy" regarding this data? I mean, some are freely available and some are not available to the public?

Comment: The EU's goal is that all countries (paying agencies) share their LPIS openly. To date this is not the case. The two above are the ones I have readily available, but there are more than these. Feel free to add more if you stumble upon them. :)

Comment: Sure, thank you again